# My post does not answer the question?

Tags: discussion

One of my answers on [How can A minor key have a sharp chord in it?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/41962/how-can-a-minor-key-have-a-sharp-chord-in-it/80678#80678) has been deleted after a comment by Doktor Mayhem:

> Hi Maika - this doesn't answer the question. Please read How to Answer for guidance.

I believe it **does** answer the question.  Why does it have to be deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question asks "How can A minor key have a sharp chord in it?"

Your post doesn't even vaguely answer that question. It is simply a list.

As we have mentioned to you many times, in your current guise and your previous one, you need to answer the specific question asked. I will point you once again to the [How do I write a good answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) page for guidance.